# The right syntax to use near '' at line 35

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

Thanks everyone, I edited the question.

I get the following error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 35

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION `distance`(Q_LAT FLOAT, Q_LONG FLOAT, NAV_LAT FLOAT, NAV_LONG FLOAT)  RETURNS float
BEGIN
DECLARE radlat1 FLOAT;
DECLARE radlat2 FLOAT;
DECLARE radlon1 FLOAT;
DECLARE radlon2 FLOAT;
DECLARE theta FLOAT;
DECLARE radtheta FLOAT;
DECLARE dist FLOAT;
DECLARE PI FLOAT;

SET PI = PI();
SET dist = 0;

IF ((Q_LAT IS NULL OR Q_LAT = 0) OR (Q_LONG IS NULL OR Q_LONG = 0)
    OR (NAV_LAT IS NULL OR NAV_LAT = 0) OR (NAV_LONG IS NULL OR NAV_LONG = 0)) THEN
    RETURN dist;
ELSE
    SET radlat1 = PI * (Q_LAT/180);
    SET radlat2 = PI * (NAV_LAT/180);
    SET radlon1 = PI * (Q_LONG/180);
    SET radlon2 = PI * (NAV_LONG/180);
    SET theta = Q_LONG-NAV_LONG;
    SET radtheta = PI * (theta/180);
    SET dist = SIN(radlat1) * SIN(radlat2) + COS(radlat1) * COS(radlat2) * COS(radtheta);
    SET dist = ACOS(dist);
    SET dist = dist * (180/PI);
    SET dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
    SET dist = dist * 1.609344;

    SET dist = CEILING(dist);

RETURN dist;
END IF;
END$$
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I missed the following info: Execute the queries seperately, there are two queries, one is to create a table and one is to create a function. The first one goes fine, but the second still returns the same error.

Comment: You code works on SQL Fiddle (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b37cf9).  Note that this requires using an option under the schema window (the last one) to set the delimited to `//`.

Comment: I ran from the `DELIMITER $$` to `END$$` via Navicat without any problems. Perhaps you should edit the question based on your comment, by removing the the part of the script that was successful for you. Then tell us where the error is occurring on your smaller script. _(I assume you are not trying to recreate the function if it already exists)_

Comment: I changed the question, the problem remains the same. I quite new at this as you might have noticed.